# How to use overridden Methods in an Activity as own Methods

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I created an App, where I get answers from my Server to my HelperClass. The HelperClass has several @override Methods. This I override this Methods in every activity different.

So now my Problem is, I get lots of Problems, casue of multi threading. For example with a simple Toast. I have to use runOnUiThread() every time. Or "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." when a overridden Helperclass method should use a (for example) MainActivity-Method to set a new layout.

Is there any solution, how I can solve those problems?

Code example:

```
public abstract class HelperClass extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    public void methodOne() {    }

    @Override
    public void methodTwo() {    }
}
```

Here are my Methods defined. An another Class gets the answer from the Server and call them. (everything works).
I override them in every Activity (here for example MainActivity)

```
public class MainActivity extends HelperClass {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);
}
@Override
public void methodOne() {
Toast.makeText(this,"text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void methodTwo() { 
setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
}
}
```

So I will get Error, when I use them without runUIThread(). I need a solution for everywhere, cause I think this is not clean. There should be a better way then using runUIthread() in every single method, when I want to use a View or something else (till now I only had this two Problems, there are still 20-30 Funktions to declare).

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your code

Comment: How do you think is `@Override` connected to multi-threading?

Comment: Sry @Turing85, I dont know the answer or dont get it. I am still a Beginner.

Comment: I did not want to hear a "correct answer". I just wanted to know what you think the connection is. I need to unterstand your misconception in order to correct it.

Comment: I add a Code example, maybe u understand me now better?